# ReadTheDocs will not autogenerate API documentation for a project that uses Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mocking, read-the-docs

I am able to use Sphinx to auto generate my project's API documentation locally, but I run into trouble when I try to use ReadTheDocs.  When ReadTheDocs builds the documentation, the API pages are all blank (see [this](http://clearplot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/clearplot.axes.html), for example).  After I read [this blog entry](http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-make-your-sphinx-documentation-compile-with-readthedocs-when-youre-using-numpy-and-scipy/), I realized the solution is to mock things like numpy and matplotlib.  So I added the following line to my `conf.py`

```
autodoc_mock_imports = ['numpy', 'matplotlib', 'matplotlib.pyplot', 'matplotlib.patches', 'matplotlib.path', 'matplotlib.lines', 'matplotlib.text', 'matplotlib.transforms', 'matplotlib.artist', 'cpickle']
```

With that addition, I cannot build the API documentation locally or on ReadTheDocs, because of the following two Sphinx issues.

Issue #1:

When I build the documentation I get the following error.

```
/Users/Ben/Documents/Python/clearplot/doc/source/api/clearplot.rst:19: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'clearplot'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Ben/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 385, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/Users/Ben/Documents/Python/clearplot/clearplot/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
mpl_version = _parse_version_string(_mpl.__version__)
File "/Users/Ben/Documents/Python/clearplot/clearplot/__init__.py", line 19, in _parse_version_string
v_list = v.split(".")
AttributeError: type object '__version__' has no attribute 'split'
```

I have confirmed that this error comes from simply doing `matplotlib.__version__.split(".")`.  I couldn't figure out how to solve this issue quickly so I commented it out.

Issue #2:

Now, I get the following error when I build the documentation.

```
/Users/Ben/Documents/Python/clearplot/doc/source/api/clearplot.rst:19: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'clearplot'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Ben/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 385, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/Users/Ben/Documents/Python/clearplot/clearplot/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
import params
File "/Users/Ben/Documents/Python/clearplot/clearplot/params.py", line 19, in <module>
_mpl.rcParams['backend'] = 'Qt4Agg'
TypeError: '_MockModule' object does not support item assignment
```

If I comment out the offending line (`_mpl.rcParams['backend'] = 'Qt4Agg'`), I get the same error for the next line because my `params` module is full of assignments to the `matplotlib.rcParams` dictionary.

Both of these issues look like a pain to fix.  Is there a better way?  If not, how should I solve Issue #1 and #2?

From reading [this](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#mocking-a-dictionary-with-magicmock) it looks like there is a work around for using dictionaries with mock.  Should I search for a similar solution for using something as basic as the string that comes from `matplotlib.__version__`?

In case it helps, the code on github is [here](https://github.com/breedlun/clearplot).